# catch -> try-catch tag synonym is wrong

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

The [catch](/questions/tagged/catch) -> [try-catch](/questions/tagged/try-catch) synonym is wrong.

Specifically, Catch is also a C++ unit testing framework. A question that wants to be tagged Catch, as in, the unit testing framework, really does not want to be tagged [try-catch](/questions/tagged/try-catch), as in the exception handling.

Comment: Why would someone need [try-catch] tag in first line?

Comment: There is a [tag:catch-unit-test] tag. Both synonyms are correct in their own way, really.

Comment: @ukaszL.: Because you have a question about exception handling? `try{ /* do something dangerous here */ } catch(Exception ex) { /* handle exception, yo */ }`

Comment: There's a catch-unit-test tag because I just made a catch-unit-test tag for one question I just had about Catch.